# How to launch Android emulator in Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: android-emulator, ubuntu-12.10

I downloaded android-sdk-linux and copied it to my local drive and extracted it. Now, when I try to create an emulator in avd manager and launch the emulator, it does not launch. It requires an environment variable of platforms and platforms-tools directory which is in android-sdk-linux. How I can create an environment variable of these two dir in Ubuntu?

Comment: This isn't the right forum for this kind of question - even though it is a good question on it's own. There is likely a different stack exchange website that will be of more use